# predict job title on the basis of skills

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, artificial-intelligence, data-science, svm

I'm working on a project where I need to predict if a person should be frontend dev, backend dev, DevOps eng or data scientist, etc on the basis of his skills.

**For example:**

Sam has skills ['python','sql','machine learning','flask'] so he can be called as *Data Scientist*.

I've scrapped LinkedIn and got the job titles of people and their skills as well. I need guidance in a few things:

1. How I can normalize data using NLP
2. How I can predict a new user that he belongs into particular job or domain.

What should be the procedure to implement it using python and any reference articles or tutorials are most appreciated thanks in advance

Comment: Ask the new user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this issue by using BERT it looked after vectorization and tokenization itself. I have a dataset that has particular skills and their domain (frontend, backend, etc). I used multi classifier to predict the domain and then that is how all the jobs are clustered through a particular domain

Comment: This answer doesn't really help any one else with a similar problem.  Please clearly explain what you did and provide examples and documentation so that this is a useful community resource.

Answer (score 1):

Here I am assuming that the methodology that you want to adopt is a ML model and not a string matching problem.
The way that I would approach this problem would be to do is:

1. Create a one-hot encoding for the skills that are present in your own dataset. This would ensure that you have a binary for all the skills that are present against the relevant job profile, an example would be as follows:

```
      python sql machine_learning flask product_management        Job   
0       1     1        1           1           0             Data_Scientist
```

2. Similarly the next step would be to convert the jobs to corresponding labels.

```
     python sql machine_learning flask product_management        Job   
0       1     1        1           1           0                  1
```

3. Now that both of the values have been set up you could use any predictive algorithms available from linear regression to using ANNs in order to predict the label of the job depending on the skill values.

The usage of NLP that I see is that, instead of converting the values using one-hot encoding you could use a custom trained tokenizer in order to break the skills into tokens and then further onto relevant vectors(tok2vec) which could be then fed into the dataframe for a prediction.

Comment: great, I've solved this issue by using BERT which was kinda similar to your technique but it looked after vectorization and tokenization itself. I have a dataset that has particular skills and their domain (frontend, backend, etc). I used multi classifier to predict the domain and then that is how all the jobs are clustered through particular domain.